# Rounding down in Python 3.3.5

Tags: python, rounding

I have a problem. I am trying to round three decimal numbers down into integers, I have already tried:

```
d.quantize
math.floor
math.trunc
int(x)
round(x)
```

and none of them have been successful.

Comment: At least `math.floor` should work. Show us the code you are using.

Comment: Give us an example of numbers you've tried, and the results you expect. This question is too vague to be answered at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `x=13.555`

Then `int(round(x))` will be 14.

There's also another way of doing this:

```
x=13.555
g=float("{0:.0f}".format(x))
int(g)
```

This prints 14.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, I have discovered what i was doing wrong and no longer need assistance.

my problem was that i wasn't assigning math.floor to anything.
i was simply writing:

math.floor(result)

instead of:

result = math.floor(result)